# created new queue and pass the queue name at Subscriber end , publisher gives error while publishing(NService Bus)

Tags: nservicebus

I have created new queue  and pass the queue name at subscriber config file. Before change the queue name was

```
<MsmqTransportConfig InputQueue="BreQueue" ErrorQueue="ErrorQueue"  NumberOfWorkerThreads="1" MaxRetries="5"/>
```

after creating new queue with name "IndusBreQueue" I have passed the queue name below like deleted the old queue i.e "BreQeue".

```
<MsmqTransportConfig InputQueue="IndusBreQueue" ErrorQueue="ErrorQueue"  NumberOfWorkerThreads="1" MaxRetries="5"/>
```

Now when publisher try to publish the message it throws error

**The destination queue 'BreQeue@APPINFOSERVER1' could not be found. You may have misconfigured the destination for this kind of message (ComEventMessage.Com_EventMessage) in the MessageEndpointMappings of the UnicastBusConfig section in your configuration file.It may also be the case that the given queue just hasn't been created yet, or has been deleted.**

Web app as a publisher and win app as subscriber. There is common message dll is being used "ComEventMessage" as reference in both application.

When I have already created the new queue and being passed as well in the config section at subscribers end then Why it is giving such error at publisher end while publishing the message?
One more confusion that if you don't delete the old queue i.e "BreQeue" it works without giving error. I mean publisher publish the message without throwing above error.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to update your subscription storage as well.
If you are using RavenDB, you need to find the subscriptions document and update it with the new name.
[image]

If you are using NH then update the table row.

If you're using an older version of NServiceBus, it's likely that MSMQ is set up as your subscription storage. You should purge all the messages from the "subscriptions" queue and then restart your solution.

Comment: Hi John Simons Thanks for your time. I am not using Raven DB. How can i do that any way. Do I need to create new subscription as well you mean?

Comment: Hi Udi Dahan I have purge all the messages from subscriptions queue but still face the same problem.